# Salesforce debug logs in eclipse?

Tags: apex, force.com, debugging, eclipse

Is there any way to view Salesforce debug logs in eclise ide? 
I tried to do some preliminary search but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you run anonymous apex in eclipse you will see the debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be able to view the debug logs for an action that you start from eclipse - running unit tests or execute anonymous.

Comment: But its only shows the testing method debug statements . Suppose if i want to make checkpoints at some lines of code in salesforce project . How do i run debug mode for salesforce ?

Comment: Is there any better force IDE for doing these all stuff ?

Comment: You should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apex Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en) (Google Chrome extension) to ease the debugging process of salesforce